# How to reload asyncData?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I fetch data from the backend by asyncData in Nuxt.js:

```
  async asyncData ({ app }) {
    const { data: { testimonials } } = await axios('https://example.com/api/testimonials.json')

    return {
      testimonials
    }
  }
```

Site is configured in the universal mode - pages are rendered on the server. But the client could have a cookie which will authenticate him to receive also private content from the CMS.

This works when navigating on client (asyncData is called with a cookies from the browser), but private content is not loaded on the first load (HTML from the server).

Is there some method to call to realod asyncData on client? I would call it from the hidden button or some other logic (e.g. there is a authentication cookie in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

You better should read cookies in server side and directly serve right content for your user!

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

You can read cookie in a nuxt route middleware, or from nuxtServerInit in the store.

Comment: I would like to host frontend (Nuxt app) on a static server, so the Nuxt server (generator) have to access only public data.

Comment: Ah, so your site is not in universal mode. But you also can using cookie-universal-nuxt. It works server side and front side.